# how to execute and read from a command line during installation of installShield exe

Tags: command-line, installshield

I am new to Install Shield, and i have a really critical requirement. In between the installation steps, the installer should run a clearcase command in the backend and then that command output should be given as an input to the next installer panel.

To be more specific, i have to give the user to select a ClearCase storage location of his choice. For this, i need to run "cleartool lsstgloc" command in the back end. This command retrieves a list of available storage locations. I should read this list and show to user in the next panel, from where he can chose the storage location of his choice.

How is this possible using installshield. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom action to run your command and store the output to an MSI property. You could run the custom action when navigating from the first dialog to the second and use the property on the second dialog to present some kind of list.

Answer (score 0):

Or how about if the command line to the installer be assigned an MSI property which is the path. For ex, create an installer property named CCPATH. Then whatever launches the installer include that as an arg:
  SETUP.EXE CCPATH=E:\CCSTORE\CASE12...
The installer properties can be used within the setup process as needed.